# Linux disk space

Tags: linux, hard-disk, disk-usage, disk

I've been looking around and I found out that you can find your disk space with `df -hT`. So I did use it to get the disk space (in total) and how much is left.
But the thing is, I wonder if there are any other ways to get the information?
The code I copied here, will give total disk space in GB's (I added the B in the end) with awk as you can see, also cut it with awk.

This might be too messy for some of you (I'm still learning bash), so if you have any recommendations, then feel free to give them to me. Remember that I am looking for options that work in every server/machine, without software that has to be downloaded with apt-get.

```
df -hT /home | awk '{print $3}' | awk 'FNR == 2 {print $1 "\B"}'
awk: cmd. line:1: warning: escape sequence `\B' treated as plain `B'
912GB
```

Also no clue how to get rid of the awk message.
This might seem a bit weird, but I have to start from somewhere!

Comment: The awk message comes from your `\B` string.  backslash means that the following  character means something different - "n" becomes a line feed, "t" becomes a tab character etc.  There is no such meaning for B hence the message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the backslash works for me:

```
df -hT /home | awk '{print $3}' | awk 'FNR == 2 {print $1 "B"}'
```

and can be simplified to

```
df -hT /home | awk 'FNR == 2 {print $3 "B"}'
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question regarding other ways to get the info,
coreutils `stat` has the ability to query for filesystem information
(the underlying syscall is `statfs`), using option `-f`. This can give
more fine-grained information than plain `df`. For example (see stat
manpage for full list of format specifiers):

```
$ stat -f /tmp --printf='{"block-size": %S, "total-blocks": %b, "free-blocks-users": %a, "free-blocks-root": %f}\n'
{"block-size": 4096, "total-blocks": 7559140, "free-blocks-users": 1693162, "free-blocks-root": 2077148}
```

A perhaps more relevant example, this will print the file system size in blocks:

```
$ stat -f /tmp --printf '%b\n'
7559140
```

Or, to compute bytes, multiply by the block size (here, using GNU dc
for the numerical computation):

```
$ stat -f /tmp --printf '%S %b *p' | dc
30962237440
```

Or, to compute the size in gigabytes with two fractional digits and
append the string "GB":

```
$ stat -f /tmp --printf '%S %b * 2k 1024 dd**/n [GB]p' | dc
28.83GB
```

Depending on the programming language you would like to use for this
task, a direct wrapper to `statfs` may be available.