# Linux machine disk space

Tags: linux, fdisk

I have already googled and found the following post

[Linux disk space](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/398006/linux-disk-space)

In there, i use the following

```
df -hT /home | awk 'FNR == 2 {print $3 "B"}'
```

to get the full size of my linux machine disk.

Sadly, this one does not work on a machine that we use as a Virtual Machine farm (all VMs run on it)

i can get the disk size with

```
fdisk -l

Device           Start        End    Sectors  Size Type

/dev/md126p1      2048     247807     245760  120M EFI System

/dev/md126p2    247808     657407     409600  200M Microsoft basic data

/dev/md126p3    657408   39062495   38405088 18,3G Microsoft basic data

/dev/md126p4  39062784  101562607   62499824 29,8G Linux swap

/dev/md126p5 101562624 5567512319 5465949696  2,6T Linux LVM
```

From here you can read out that the full size is 2.6T (2.6TB aka 2600GB)

Are there any other way to get this? also, does someone already have a way to grep/cut this out quick?

Comment: There's not enough information. What linux distro are you using? What package manager do you have there?

Comment: Debian. Different versions of it. No idea how to check the package mangers.

Comment: And also, "this one does not work".  What does not work?  Which error are you getting?

Comment: It works but not how i want it to. It only shows me /home/ directory size which is right now 40GB. The whole host size is 2.6TB

Comment: You're only seeing `/home` because you're asking to only see `/home`.  Use `df -hT` to see sizes of _all_ mounted partitions.

Comment: Why use "df" if the information you need comes from "fdisk"?

Answer (score 0):

```
df -h /
```

will give you the size of the disk mounted as root, in human-easily-readable format. It's part of the `coreutils` package on RHEL/CentOS so I suppose it works on all distros.

Comment: Not what i can use, i already used df as noted above.